# Array received as prop from parent used as a dependency of useMemo triggers infinite re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, memoization

I have a component that looks like this

```
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react'
import Input from '~/components/Input'
import Fuse from 'fuse.js'

interface Props {
  data: any[]
  keys: string[]
  onUpdate: (data: any[]) => void
  placeholder: string
}

const FilterInput = ({ data, keys, onUpdate, placeholder }: Props) => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('')
  const handleSearch = (e) => setSearch(e.target.value)

  // Memorize the fuse instance to avoid recreating it on every render
  const fuse = useMemo(() => {
    return new Fuse(data, {
      includeScore: true,
      keys,
      threshold: 0.3,
      distance: 100,
    })
  }, [data, keys]) //THIS IS THE RELEVANT PART

  useEffect(() => {
    const results =
      search === '' ? data : fuse.search(search).map((result) => result.item)
    onUpdate(results) // Invoke onUpdate with the filtered or original list
  }, [search, fuse, onUpdate, data]) // Effect dependencies

  return (
    <div className={'mb-10'}>
      <Input value={search} onChange={handleSearch} placeholder={placeholder} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default FilterInput
```

I am using it like this

```
const ProjectFeatureListing = ({ projects }: Props) => {
  const [filteredProjects, setFilteredProjects] = useState(projects) // State to hold the filtered list
  console.log(projects)
  return (
    <div className={'max-w-7xl py-10 mx-auto px-10'}>
      <FilterInput
        data={projects}
        keys={['title', 'description']}
        onUpdate={setFilteredProjects}
        placeholder={'Find our creators'}
      />
...
```

I can't figure out why sending this static array would trigger a re-render since it's not changing, to be clear when I do this

```
  const fuse = useMemo(() => {
    return new Fuse(data, {
      includeScore: true,
      keys,
      threshold: 0.3,
      distance: 100,
    })
  }, [data]) //THIS IS THE RELEVANT PART
```

It does NOT infinitely re-render

===

UPDATE:

I added this code

```
// Ref to store the previous keys
  const prevKeysRef = useRef(keys)

  // Check if keys have the same reference
  const keysHaveSameReference = keys === prevKeysRef.current

  console.log('Keys have the same reference:', keysHaveSameReference)

  // Update prevKeysRef with the current keys
  useEffect(() => {
    prevKeysRef.current = keys
  }, [keys])
```

And I can confirm that the ref to keys is changing

Answer (score 0):

Probably, when `onUpdate` in your `useEffect` changes the state of `ProjectFeatureListing`, the rerender recreates the `['title', 'description']` object and the `FilterInput` gets a new reference to another object with the same properties, which is why the callback in useMemo is called and the `fuse` variable changes, when changed, `useEffect` is called with `onUpdate` and everything starts all over again.

Comment: Ok, I think i follow but I'm still not sure how to solve it.

Comment: You can move this array ['title', 'description'] outside the ProjectFeatureListing component as a constant, or, if you plan to change it in the future, put it in a separate state.

Comment: The thing is, this puts the responsibility on the parent to not send an inlined array, I want the child component to take care of it

Comment: Then you can try something like what was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65125885/usememo-with-an-array-dependency

Answer (score 0):

I've found a possible solution

```
let fuse = useRef(
    new Fuse(data, {
      includeScore: true,
      keys: keys,
      threshold: 0.3, // Adjust the strictness of the search
      distance: 100, // Adjust how far the algorithm looks for a match
    }),
  )
```

use a reference so that fuse is only created once.